# Execution time PHP vs MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I have a simple question.

Lets say I have two methods of doing a simple `sum` of values. I can do it with PHP

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $total += $row->column;
}
```

Or I can do it that I can run a query in MySQL database to do the sum

```
"SELECT sum(column) FROM table";
```

Which one would finish first. Assuming there are multiple queries already running in a function like

```
public function abc()
{
      //Query 1 Execution from MySQL
      //Query 2 Execution from MySQL

      //Then comes the "SELECT sum(column) FROM table";
      //OR
      //foreach()
}
```

Comment: why not test it yourself?

Comment: the SUM on the database would be better

Comment: `sum` would be faster.

Comment: I would say that id depends. If you need to get the results and iterate through them anyway, then the PHP version would probably be faster (since it would otherwise require you to do an extra request). But if you're fetching all the rows _just_ to get the sum, then the database sum would definitely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the DBMS (in this case mysql) is optimized to do sum and other calculations that outperform a loop in php. In case you have doubts because there are other things that are needed in your script, you can always do this:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Your code here
.
.
.

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
```

In the section of your code you can try the different scenarios that you have.